# Unable to change Travis-CI PHP memory_limit

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, travis-ci

I’m having troubles in testing with php5.6 and composer: builds run [out of memory](https://travis-ci.org/2amigos/yii2-usuario/jobs/403454211) (tried also with 2G limit instead of -1 but [still fails](https://travis-ci.org/maxxer/yii2-usuario/jobs/403459056)).

I followed other examples and [Travis' PHP guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/) to disable memory limit, but it’s apparently not having the desired result.

Lastly I’ve added [the oneliner](https://github.com/maxxer/yii2-usuario/commit/bbd6ce62507ec142ee3b0dd4e0693229d7cfa108)

```
echo "memory_limit=2G" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/conf.d/travis.ini
```

but composer install still fails after 1.5G.

Why is the limit not applied? According to [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors) changing the value in php.ini should be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By more and more carefully reading the log (and better understanding TravisCI) I found out `before_script` is being run **after** dependency installation, so was not yet in effect when running composer.

I fixed by increasing the memory limit in `before_install`, by adding the following to .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
  - echo "memory_limit=2G" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/conf.d/travis.ini
```

*edit*: as pointed out by @emix in the comments this is **not the best way** because this raises the memory for the full application, which could hide memory leaks.

**The best way** is to raise memory just for composer run, which can be accomplished by running composer this way:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 travis_retry composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction
```

Comment: You can simply run composer without the limit as follows: `php -dmemory_limit=-1 composer install ...`. It's better not to have unusually large memory limit for PHP globally, because you could miss issues in your code regarding high memory consumption.

Comment: good point. if you know how to do it in Travis, that would be great :)